# Can not find any device when I run Genymotion

Tags: android

Can not find any device when I run Genymotion.

Why nothing to show?

[image: why nothing to show]

Answer (score 0):

Ok you Must Enable **Developer Options**

And It Different From Device to Another

But You can Find It here

1. Go to Setting
2. About Phone
3. Tap many Time On **Build number**
4. till Developer Option Appear

Then You Will Find **Developer Options** in your setting

open it and then Enable **USB debugging**

and then your Device Will Appear in Run List